# Automatic reformatting when using csv writer python module

Tags: python, csv, writer

How do I prevent Python from automatically writing objects into csv as a different format than originally? For example, I have list object such as the following:

```
row = ['APR16', '100.00000']
```

I want to write this row as is, however when I use writerow function of csv writer, it writes into the csv file as 16-Apr and just 10. I want to keep the original formatting.

EDIT:

Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd

dates = ['APR16', 'MAY16', 'JUN16']
numbers = [100.00000, 200.00000, 300.00000]

for i in range(3):
    row = []
    row.append(dates[i])
    row.append(numbers[i])
    prow = pd.DataFrame(row)
    prow.to_csv('test.csv', index=False, header=False)
```

And result:

[image: Result]

Comment: How do you know it's Python that's doing that, and not that whatever you're reading it into is interpreting it that way?

Comment: So you're saying that Excel is changing the object to Date format and so on? How would I go about changing that setting then that automatically reformats the data when writing to it?

Comment: If you want to have them inline see: [this](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/dsintro.html#from-structured-or-record-array)

`pd.DataFrame([(dates[i], numbers[i])])`

Comment: This is no longer a Python question, but an Excel question.  Use "Data/From Text" (see [here](http://superuser.com/questions/483387/microsoft-excel-maintain-formatting-when-importing)) and set the imported column type to be Text, not General.

Answer (score 0):

Using `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd

dates = ['APR16', 'MAY16', 'JUN16']
numbers = [100.00000, 200.00000, 300.00000]

data = zip(dates,numbers) 

fd = pd.DataFrame(data)

fd.to_csv('test.csv', index=False, header=False)  # csv-file
fd.to_excel("test.xls", header=False,index=False) # or xls-file
```

**Result in my terminal:**

```
➜  ~  cat test.csv 
APR16
100.00000
```

**Result in LibreOffice:**

[image]

Comment: I have multiple rows, each being declared within a for loop. With this code it seems to keep rewriting over the file.

Comment: post a piece of code to make your point clearer. I don't see why the above solution should'nt do for multiple rows

Comment: Well either way it still converts the APR16 to a date when I view it in Excel, it's an issue with the way it is being interpreted as mentioned above

Comment: "it" still converts you say. What is "it"? Excel or Python? Anyway, see the screenshot in my answer. It looks fine, I would say.. Post your code with the loop so we can look to it.

Comment: Edited question above

Comment: @KidSudi: See my edited solution. In your loop with `row = []` you reset your list each time! That is not what you want to do, right:-)

Comment: Well that's not an issue for me, I can fix that. I'm still getting the same problem as I stated in my question. It's definitely an issue with the way it is being interpreted

Comment: [..] it is beeing interpreted by Excel. You need to have a look at the properties of the cell in Excel. Maybe that can help.